# Display form validation errors in formset when extra=0

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a form that has the following custom clean() method:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        event_date = cleaned_data.get("event_date")
        location = cleaned_data.get("location")

        if event_date and location:
            cleaned_data['relevance'] = True
        else:
            cleaned_data['relevance'] = False
            raise forms.ValidationError("You need to supply at least Event and Location information")

        return cleaned_data
```

I would like to show the user the ValidationError so they can fix their error.
However, the formset that creates this form has extra=0 set, like so:

```
CodingFormSet = formset_factory(CodingForm, extra=0)
if request.method=='POST':
        
        [...]
        
        elif "coding_form_save" in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")

            process_form(formset, request, current_page, paginator)
            
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            
            redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

def process_form(formset, request, current_page, paginator):
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset.forms:
        form = form.cleaned_data
        
        if form["relevance"] == False:
            pass
        elif form["relevance"] == True:
            
            event_form = EventRecordForm()
        
            event = event_form.save(commit=False)
            event.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
            event.coder = request.user
            event.last_updated = datetime.datetime.today()
            event.event_date = form["event_date"]
            event.location = form["location"]
            event.actors = form["actors"]
            event.num_participants = form["num_participants"]
            event.issue = form["issue"]
            event.side = form["side"]
            event.scope = form["scope"]
            event.part_violence = form["part_violence"]
            event.sec_engagement = form["sec_engagement"]
            event.save()
    
    ##### Add info on who worked on the article when
    history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
    article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
    article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
    article_history.coder = request.user
    article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    article_history.save()
```

Is there a way to keep extra=0 and still show the user validation errors?
**Update**:
Thanks to @Alasdair I can show the Validation Errors now, by redirecting only if the form is valid. The code now looks like this:

```
def assignment(request, pk):
"""View for each assignment"""
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    
    #### Get correct articles
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    country = assignment.country.cowcode
    start_date = assignment.start_date
    end_date = assignment.end_date
    articles = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date))
    
    #### Pagination ####
    paginator = Paginator(articles, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator(page(paginator.num_pages))
    
    # Check if on first page and enable redirect
    if page is None:
        current_page = 1
    else:
        current_page = page
    redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page

    ##### Show already created events on the page
    current_article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
    EventFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventRecord, can_delete=True, exclude=('coder','article','url','last_updated'), extra=0)
    event_queryset = EventRecord.objects.filter(article__id=current_article.id).filter(coder=request.user.id)
    coded_events = EventFormSet(queryset=event_queryset, prefix="event_form")
    
    last_updated = ArticleHistory.objects.filter(coder=request.user.id).filter(article__id=current_article.id).order_by('-pk')[0]
    ##### Create Forms    
    CodingFormSet = formset_factory(CodingForm, extra=0)
    
    ###### Get correct locations
    location_queryset = Geonames.objects.filter(cowcode=country).order_by('name')
    
    if request.method=='POST':
        
    ##### Check if coder wants to go to next page or stay
        if "coding_form_next" in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")


            process_form(formset, request, current_page, paginator, next_article, coded_events, location_queryset)
            
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
        
            #current_page = int(current_page) + 1
            #redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        
        elif "coding_form_save" in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")
            

            process_form(CodingFormSet, formset, request, current_page, paginator, next_article, coded_events, location_queryset)
            
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            
            #redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    
        elif 'add_event' in request.POST:
            
            cp = request.POST.copy()
            cp['coding_form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp['coding_form-TOTAL_FORMS'])+ 1
            formset = CodingFormSet(cp,prefix='coding_form')
                    
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
        elif 'save_changes' in request.POST:
            formset = CodingFormSet(prefix="coding_form")
            changed_events = EventFormSet(request.POST, prefix="event_form")
            instances = changed_events.save()
            
            update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)
            
            history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
            article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
            article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
            article_history.coder = request.user
            article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            article_history.save()
            
            EventFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventRecord, can_delete=True, exclude=('coder','article','url','last_updated'), extra=0)
            event_queryset = EventRecord.objects.filter(article__id=current_article.id).filter(coder=request.user.id)
            coded_events = EventFormSet(queryset=event_queryset, prefix="event_form")
    else:
        formset = CodingFormSet(request.POST or None,prefix="coding_form")
        
        update_location_set(formset, coded_events, location_queryset)

else:
    print ERROR
return render(request, 'coding/assignment.html', 
{'articles':articles,'assignment':assignment,'formset':formset,'coded_events':coded_events,'last_updated':last_updated})

def process_form(CodingFormSet, formset, request, current_page, paginator, next_article, coded_events, location_queryset):
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset.forms:
        form = form.cleaned_data
        
        if form["relevance"] == False:
            pass
        elif form["relevance"] == True:
            
            event_form = EventRecordForm()
        
            event = event_form.save(commit=False)
            event.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
            event.coder = request.user
            event.last_updated = datetime.datetime.today()
            event.event_date = form["event_date"]
            event.location = form["location"]
            event.actors = form["actors"]
            event.num_participants = form["num_participants"]
            event.issue = form["issue"]
            event.side = form["side"]
            event.scope = form["scope"]
            event.part_violence = form["part_violence"]
            event.sec_engagement = form["sec_engagement"]
            event.save()
    
    ##### Add info on who worked on the article when
    history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
    article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
    article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
    article_history.coder = request.user
    article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    article_history.save()
    
    
    redirect_to = "?page=%s" % current_page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
```

What is different now, however, ist best shown in three pictures:
In the old code, after hitting `save`a coder would see the following:
[image: The old way]

Now, after hitting `save` a coder sees this:
[image]
This looks like he didn't hit save at all.

And only after hitting `save` again or reloading the page, he or she sees this:
[image]

I would like to go back to the first picture, where the coders sees the coded event and no new form with the same info in it. Note that his happens because I shifted two lines of code around and did nothing else.
Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that having `extra=0` is related to whether the errors are displayed.

The following pattern is very common when dealing with formsets:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST"
        formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")
        if formset.is_valid():
            do_something_with_formset()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/success_url/")
    else:
        formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, prefix="coding_form")
    return render(request, "my_template.html", {'formset': formset}
```

When the request method is GET, a blank formset is rendered. When the formset is invalid, the formset is rendered, and will display the errors. We only redirect if the formset is valid.

In your case, you always redirect when the request method is POST, regardless of whether the formset is valid or not. Therefore, you'll never see the errors when formset is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawlessly! :) However, when I now redirect to the same page in is_valid(), I get the filled out form again, where before I got shown no forms. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Your code does not redirect now, because you have removed the `return HttpRedirectResponse()` from your view. Returning a redirect from your `process_form` function has no effect, since you do not return that in the view. Your view is more complicated than my example, but it can still be rearranged to follow the same outline. You need to trace through the code paths for GET requests, POST requests with invalid data, and POST requests with valid data, and make sure you are returning an appopriate response for each.

Comment: It was as easy as moving `if formset.is_valid()` out of `process_form` and back to `assignment`! Thanks so much for your help!